# Does creating a new asymmetric key on a new database server causes old data invalidation?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, encryption-asymmetric

I don't know about encryption keys much. But I got a project where I need to transfer SQL Server database from one computer to another. I can't connect it online as the database needs to be local only. Also I generated create scripts of complete database using SSMS. But create scripts of asymmetric keys are not generated. I want to know that if I create asymmetric key with the password given by the project owner, will old data still be validated from it? I mean does asymmetric key is system independent?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend getting an overview on column level encryption through a book, video, technical session during a SQL Saturday or other means. Even though I am going to provide the solution, you need a solid understanding of how the encryption system works so that you will understand how to avoid losing encrypted data by making a mistake. That said, the solution is to backup the database, then backup the Database Master Key providing a password to encrypt the key in the file specified. Migrate the files to the destination server then restore the database and restore the Database Master Key using the password previously provided. This will complete the encryption hierarchy. Since all database keys, including asymmetric and symmetric keys, are backed up with the database, they will be transferred to the destination server in the backup file.